# Ретранслятор на Erlyvideo

Tags: видео, сервер

Мы арендовали сервер, установили Erlyvideo и nginx. Требуется сделать такое: Ерлувидео получает с другого сервера поток rtmp и ретранслирует его, при этом еще и производит запись в папку на сервере. Как это организовать? Если кто знает, напишите подробно пошагово, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Запись в папку на сервере может осуществлять flussonic — третья версия erlyvideo.